# How do we talk about the future in English if something is not 100% certain to happen?

Tags: future-time

How we will make sentence in English if  something will  happen in the future but still it is not 100 % sure? There is probability he may or may not be doing that particular work.

Comment: In your question, you say "he **may** or **may not** be" doing something. Have you consulted a dictionary to learn about the modal verbs [**may**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/may) and [**could?**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/could) You **may** find that you **could** answer your own question!

Answer (score 3):

He *might* be doing the same kind of work next year.

[Might](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/might):

> (used to express possibility): They might be at the station.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is 100%  certain  to happen in the future. So *any way*  of referring to the future in  English is acceptable to refer to something that is not 100% certain  to happen. For instance  the way of expressing the strongest possible "certainty" about the future is the simple present. So, for example,  you can say *Tomorrow I leave at 7am*. Nevertheless you can't be  100% certain that you will actually leave at 7.

Thus  you should really clarify your sentence by adding some context.

Comment: actually I came across a sentence which was about a toxic gas which is under research . It was written that if this gas affects insects, then human "might be affected" from this gas. So this "might be affected" here indicates for future?

Comment: yes, just like the answer by @J.Doe states. I upvoted that answer, and I have no idea why it had at least two downvotes but the voting system on SE and ELL is extremely unreliable and sometimes extremely misleading.

Comment: So Joe is correct?

Comment: Yes , Joe is correct here.

Comment: The present continuous is often used for plans, and pre-arrangements: "Tomorrow I am leaving at 7am". But I think the OP is talking about the modals, *might* and *will*, both of whom are used to express uncertainty in the future. E.g. "I might be leaving tomorrow at 7pm" and "I think we'll be leaving for Moscow tomorrow at 7pm. I'm not absolutely certain, I need to check the flight number."

Comment: @Mari-LouA In *I think we'll be leaving for Moscow tomorrow at 7pm. I'm not absolutely certain, I need to check the flight number*, the uncertainty has nothing to do with the modal *will*.  The modal *will* is not "used to express uncertainty in the future", as you incorrectly and unfortunately say. If you disagree, please provide evidence from a credible source.

Comment: Perhaps I was confusing it with hypothesis, if making a hypothesis in the far future without existing evidence, it is quite natural to use "will". *In a hundred years time, man will inhabit Mars.*  There's nothing certain about that statement, but "will" is used.